# Trying to import file from SD card in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, import, android-sdcard

New to Xamarin and Android, currently working my way through a program that needs to be updated to import a file from an SD Card. See below block of code.

```
 string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;

            string importFile = "/storage/emulated/0/LumberData/" + "export-icsep.txt";

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(importFile))
            {
                ShowErrorDialog("Import File not found. Please contact supervisor", null);
                return;

            }
```

I am trying to find out the new syntax that is being used for importing of files. Currently when debugging it fails the import and and displays the error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you getting the path for `ExternalStorageDirectory` but then not using it?

Comment: Dont post your constants but give real values. How would we know what you are doing? Tell complete full path you tried.

Comment: Did you request the storage permission before you run the code and did the file is created by your app?